# Split a file into sections and set them to a variable

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
1,02/09/15,18:00,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc
2,03/09/15,18:00,M’lady,Napoleon Wilson,Y,Napoleon Wilson
3,04/09/15,18:00,Ripley,Billy Casper,Y,Billy Casper
4,05/09/15,18:00,Jenkins,Tyler,Y,Jenkins
```

And I need to split them, and then set them to a variable to be printed. This is the code I have so far

```
f = open("fireside.txt", "r")
line = f.readlines()
game=input("Type in your estimate number")
for line in open("fireside.txt"):
    line=line.strip()
    gamenumber, date, time, player1,player2, played, winner= line.split(",")
if gamenumber== game:
    print(gamenumber)
    print(date)
    print(player1)
    print(player2)
    print(played)
    print(winner)
```

and then im greated with this error message:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 7, got 1)
```

If there's any error in the code please edit it, or if there's an easier way to attempt this task

Comment: You might want to check if you have empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: You may want to indent the code so that if statement is inside for loop.

Comment: I've done all of that, but I still end with the same error message, is there anything else I could try

Comment: Can you please try putting print(line) statement after line.strip() inside for loop and tell us the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file and reading the data twice, with

```
f = open("fireside.txt", "r")
line = f.readlines()
```

and

```
for line in open("fireside.txt"):
    line=line.strip()
```

Both ways are fine but you should only do one. And remember to close your file. The best way is to use a file context which closes it for you at the end:

```
with open("fireside.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I still end up with the same error message, is there anyway to fix this